# Exception about the lack of primary attribute in an entity

Tags: spring-boot, scala, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am a newbie with spring boot and Cassandra and I'm trying to connect both to build an API. The project is written in Scala to learn from this too.

This is main application:

```
object Application {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args: _*)
  }
}

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = Array(classOf[CassandraDataAutoConfiguration], classOf[CassandraAutoConfiguration]))
class Application
```

This is a controller:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/api/user"))
class UserController @Autowired()(userService: UserService) {

  @GetMapping(value = Array("/{email}"))
  def findByEmail(@PathVariable("email") email: String): ResponseEntity[User] = {
    try {
      val user = userService.findByEmail(email)

      if(user.isEmpty) {
        return new ResponseEntity[User](HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
      }
      new ResponseEntity[User](user.get, HttpStatus.OK)
    }
    catch {
      case _ => new ResponseEntity[User](HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }
  }
}
```

This is a service:

```
@Service
class UserService @Autowired()(userRepository: UserRepository) {
  def findByEmail(email: String): Option[User] = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
}
```

This is a repository:

```
@Repository
trait UserRepository extends RepositoryBase[User, String] {
  def findByEmail(email: String): Option[User] = {
    this.findByPrimaryKey(email)
  }
}
```

This is a entity:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.{NotBlank, Size}
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.{CassandraType, Column, PrimaryKey, Table}

@Table(value = "user")
class User (

    @NotBlank
    @Column(value = "id")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.UUID)
    var id: String,

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 10)
    @PrimaryKey(value = "email")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    var email: String,

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 8, max = 250)
    @Column(value = "password")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    var password: String,

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3)
    @Column(value = "name")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    var name: String

) extends Serializable {}
```

This is Cassandra config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
case class CassandraConfig (

  @Value(value = "${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
  keySpace: String,

  @Value(value = "${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
  contactPoints: String,

  @Value(value = "${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
  port: Int

) extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration
{
  override def getKeyspaceName: String = this.keySpace

  override def getContactPoints: String = this.contactPoints

  override def getPort: Int = this.port

  @Bean
  @throws(classOf[ClassNotFoundException])
  override def cassandraMapping(): CassandraMappingContext = {
    new BasicCassandraMappingContext()
  }
}
```

This is the table cql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_data.user (
    id uuid,
    email text,
    password text,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
) WITH comment = 'user data';
```

I have been reading all spring boot documentation, and in my entity I have @Table and @PrimaryKey annotations, but still I get this error:

```
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.fail(BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:117) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:90) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.lambda$verify$0(CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:67) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:67) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.java:157) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:452) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:406) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(CassandraMappingContext.java:337) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:291) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:209) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.java:75) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: @Table types must have only one primary attribute, if any; Found 0
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:87) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
```

Could it be that the error is from the Cassandra configuration?
I'm also open to any best practice suggestions for anything unrelated to the bug.
Thanks!

Comment: Your User entity is annotated with `@Table`. Have you checked if it comes from the right package? If I am not wrong the right one is `org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table`

Comment: @thepaoloboi the ```@Table``` annotation is correct. I add the entity imports in the question so you can see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the entity. The attributes of the entity must not be declared in the constructor as would be done normally in Scala, so that the entity can be mapped correctly the attributes must be declared in this way:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.{NotBlank, Size}
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.{CassandraType, Column, PrimaryKey, Table}
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

@Table(value = "user")
class User extends Serializable {

    @NotBlank
    @BeanProperty
    @Column(value = "id")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.UUID)
    var id: String = _

    @NotBlank
    @BeanProperty
    @Size(min = 10)
    @PrimaryKey(value = "email")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    var email: String = _

    @NotBlank
    @BeanProperty
    @Size(min = 8, max = 250)
    @Column(value = "password")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    var password: String = _

    @NotBlank
    @BeanProperty
    @Size(min = 3)
    @Column(value = "name")
    @CassandraType(`type` = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    var name: String = _
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED]** It looks like `BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java` class is looking for at least a `@PartitionKey` to be present.

In any case, I've requested one of the devs to respond to your question directly because I don't have a ready-made example for you. Cheers!

Comment: data-cassandra ```@Table``` annotation only contains the ```value``` and ```forceQuote``` attributes, there is not ```name```

Comment: I've been looking in the data-cassandra documentation and haven't found any @PartitionKey annotations. I hope the dev can add an example. Greeting.